# Uploading database data from EC2 to empty RDS Postgresql Database

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have a local PostGresql database with 2 tables, which I dumped using pg_dump into a single file (file.sql), which I uploaded to an EC2 Instance.

I created a PostGresql RDS Instance, but can't figure out how I can upload the exported data to the exisitng postgres inside RDS - I have read a lot of articles and pages worth of documentation from amazon, but can't seem to find an easy and quick way - and besides, almost every ressource I read suggests to do something different, and since I'm quite new to AWS, I'm kind of lost on how to tackle this... Could anyone point me towards the right direction?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: You would just run `pg_restore`, like you would to restore the `pg_dump` data into a PostgreSQL instance running anywhere else.

Comment: should I do this from the EC2 instance? Is the RDS DB autmatically "connected" to my EC2 since it's on the same account?

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! yes indeed, I just had a look at it... Thank's again!!!